# Python Executable / Pyodbc and sql interface Error about when distributing the .exe to other people

Tags: python, sql, pyinstaller

I have an sql connection as per below:

```py
from sqlalchemy.engine import URL
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

connection_string = 'DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=server_name;DATABASE=db_name;UID=username;PWD=password'

connection_url = URL.create("mssql+pyodbc", query={"odbc_connect": connection_string})
engine = create_engine(connection_url)
conn = engine.connect()
```

This works fine for me as a python script but also as an executable when I pack it using pyinstaller.

However, when I distribute to other people the `.exe` from pyinstaller they get the following error

> sqlalchemy.exc.interfaceError: (pyodbc.InterfaceError) Cim0e2',
> '(1M002] [Microsoft][008C Driver Manager] The data source name was not
> found and no default driver was specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
> (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.ne/e/14/rvf5)

any idea why and how can I fix it?

Comment: There's seemingly a typo in that error URL but changing .ne to .me leads to https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/errors.html#error-rvf5

Comment: Most likely, the ODBC data source required by your connection string does not exist on other computers.